# unable to use .col() method in polars rust

Tags: dataframe, rust, rust-polars

i am trying to execute this line in my rust programme:

```
let filtered_df = df.filter(col("time").eq(cursor_date_str)).head(Some(1));
```

and the compiler returns that

```
error[E0425]: cannot find function `col` in this scope
  --> src/main.rs:50:37
   |
50 |         let filtered_df = df.filter(col("time").eq(cursor_date_str)).head(Some(1));
   |                                     ^^^ not found in this scope
```

even though i have imported all from prelude:

```
use polars::prelude::*;
```

and my polars is up to date as well:

```
polars = "0.30.0"
```

Comment: Does `use polars::lazy::prelude::*;` work?

Comment: It seems you need to activate the `lazy` feature

Comment: no luck. returns error[E0433]: failed to resolve: could not find `lazy` in `polars`

Comment: Can you try modifying your Cargo.toml with something like this `polars = { version = "0.30.0, features = ["lazy"] }`?
`

Comment: i wonder though why this is not mentioned in official docs.

Comment: It's on the [first page of the guide](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars-book/getting-started/intro/) and also on the [docs.rs page](https://docs.rs/polars/latest/polars/#compile-times-and-opt-in-features).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to enable `lazy` feature in *Cargo.toml*.

```
[dependencies]
polars = { version = "0.30.0", features = ["lazy"] }
```

Note: I could not find anything other than [this in the official documentation](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars-book/user-guide/installation/#rust), But I got this hint after looking at the source code of `polars` [which defines it's `prelude.rs` file like this](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/blob/rs-0.30.0/polars/src/prelude.rs#L8-L10).

```
#[cfg(feature = "polars-algo")]
pub use polars_algo::prelude::*;
pub use polars_core::frame::groupby::*;
pub use polars_core::prelude::*;
pub use polars_core::utils::NoNull;
#[cfg(feature = "polars-io")]
pub use polars_io::prelude::*;
#[cfg(feature = "lazy")]
pub use polars_lazy::prelude::*; //`col` comes from `polars_lazy` crate
pub use polars_ops::prelude::*;
#[cfg(feature = "temporal")]
pub use polars_time::prelude::*;
```